# suPHP permission requirements for all files or only PHP scripts?

Tags: php, permissions, suphp

Generally with PHP, files/folders have a permission of `0777` when we want to write to them. suPHP forbids a permission of `0777`. Instead, files are supposed to have a permission of `0644` and folders have a permission `0755`. However, this is always worded differently

- [SuPHP won't allow chmod of 777 so we need to set all files to 644 and directories to 755](http://digiground.com/linux-tips-a-tricks/195-installing-suphp-on-ubuntu-1004)
- [Your scripts and directories can now, only have a maximum of 755 permissions](https://pacifichost.zendesk.com/entries/20154273-running-with-suphp)
- [Set file permission(s) to allow read access only by you (e.g., chmod 600 filename.suphp).](http://its.virginia.edu/websupport/suphp.html)

What is the exact rule and to what files does it apply to? If I have `README` file somewhere in a nested directory does its permission need to be updated, or does it only apply to `.php` files?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the ownership of the file/directory. Just remember, PHP under suPHP will access PHP scripts as the owner user, and those PHP scripts will operate as that user, meaning, everything they read or write is done as that user. So, PHP scripts only need to be owner-readable to run.

However, anything else not being a PHP script is accessed as the Apache user (they are not accessed by suPHP), meaning that user need at least read access to the files and read+execute access to directories. If those files are owned by a common user, they will need to be world-readable (and world-executable for directories). But if they are owned by the web server user (nobody, www-data, apache, depending on distro) they only need to be owner-readable/owner-executable.

A note for directories: Apache (when serving non-PHP files) will try to read every directory in the path searching for .htaccess files, if it cannot explore the directories, it will fail with a 403 error, even if the file is readable.

So, I think for most websites or web applications all files (PHP files and non-PHP files, and directories) would be owned by a single user, so the permissions would be:

- PHP scripts: 0400  (u+r), or 0600 (u+rw) if PHP need to modify them.
- non-PHP files: 0444 (ugo+r), or 0644 (u+rw,go+r) if PHP need to modify them.
- directories: 0555 (ugo+rx), or 0755 (u+rwx,go+rx) if PHP need to create files in them.

Another note: even if you set 0400 for a PHP script, it can be modified by another PHP script owned by the same user, as it can simply run chmod from PHP, so a 0400 is not safer than 0644. This apply only when using suPHP.

Comment: Generally I would avoid setting any file with executable code to anything with +w. At best the executing user should also have no rights to change the permissions. Otherwise someone exploiting the web application could easily inject custom code, which is worst case.

Comment: Yes, that's why some people don't like suPHP (or suEXEC), because any PHP script is run as its owner, allowing to modify anything (including permissions) owned by he/she, making impossible to really lock down the scripts using file permissions. On the other hand, it restrict any potential damage to only one user (that's why it is so popular in hosting servers).

Comment: Hm… Okay, so that limits it a bit. However, my experience and what I've heard from php I doubt that this works non exploitable ;). Jokes aside, I stick with selinux. Just thought I'd share my objections on +w on code files.